# How to process and decode incoming bytes from a TCP server

Tags: java, tcp, byte, decoding

I am currently working on a Java console application. It is run through the command prompt, connects to a server application coded in python and communicates with that server over TCP. My application sends "ISND" string to server which it accepts and in return server sends three images. The format in which Images are sent in is

Where "<"">" are not actually included. "ISND" is encoded into bytes using ascii. Size is the size of the image converted into bytes from int and it is always composed of 3 bytes regardless of the size of the image. For each individual image, a message in this format is sent.

I have been using BufferedReader to read server responses but at this point, I am at a loss on how to actually handle this message. I searched for ways to separate the incoming message into components since I know the length of the first two parts which are always fixed yet I couldn't find a way to actually accomplish that goal.

It has come to the point it feels like I am smashing my head into a wall. As such, I need advice from anyone that is more familiar with Java and Socket programming on how to handle this issue.

My current code

```
public class ImageLabeler {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String IP = args[0];
    System.out.println(IP + "\n");

    String port = args[1];
    System.out.println(port + "\n");

    Socket clientSocket;
    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    BufferedReader inFromServer = null;

    String serverResponse;



    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(IP, Integer.parseInt(port));
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connection success\n");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outToServer, true);

    try {
        //outToServer.writeBytes("USER bilkentstu\\n");
        //outToServer.flush();
        //System.out.println("check\n");
        writer.println("USER bilkentstu");

        serverResponse = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverResponse + "\n");

        writer.println("PASS cs421f2019");

        //outToServer.writeBytes("PASS cs421f2019\\r\\n");
        //outToServer.flush();

        serverResponse = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverResponse + "\n");

        writer.println("IGET");
        //This is where I need to handle the incoming Image messages.

        writer.println("EXIT");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageLabeler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use buffered reader. You need to write the code reading a string from the InputStream of the socket one byte at a time.

Comment: Yep. Managed to figure that one out. Ended up binding a inputStreamReader(which went into BufferedReader) and a DataInputStream to socket's own inputStream. Used DataInputStream when I received Image file responses and the bufferedReader for everything else since only image file responses required byte by byte reading.